# Use 32 character guid in where clause in JPA

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have column in mysql datatype is BINARY(16) that stores the guid sent from java code using hibernate. Mysql converts the 32 character GUID to its hex formats and saves it. While querying I want to use the original guid (32 character) to fetch row form this table but unable to do so.  Getting entity not found. Please help on the same. Thanks

Comment: If querying with it you should convert the GUID into the same format as the column itself to avoid type conversions and enable index use.

Comment: The log tells you the SQL invoked. Why not look at it ?!